# How to set static SVG size for `<g id="child">` element under `<svg id="parent">` element that gets transform attr

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, zooming

Main Question:

Is there a way to set a static width and height on `<g>` elements so that they don't get effected by transform attribute done on its parent view-box `<svg>` element?

i.e.

`<svg id="viewbox" transform="translate(1,5)scale(2)"> 
    // continuously gets the transform attr via js upon zoom event
    <g>
        <path "the shape of a triangle"/>
        <path same/>
        <path same/>
        <path same/>
        <path same/>
    </g>
</svg>`

I want everything under the `<g>` element to translate according to the zoom event transform values that the `<svg>` view-box receives, but not scale the dimensions of the `<g>` element. So that it looks like the screen is zooming into one section of the view-box, but without the `<g>` elements changing dimensions.

Comment: I believe the only way to keep it from scaling (or appearing to scale) would be to scale it the inverse of the parent scaling. But someone smarter than me may have a better idea.

Comment: Maybe this answer is what you need: [How to set an element with relative positioning in absolute dimensions in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53246241/how-to-set-an-element-with-relative-positioning-in-absolute-dimensions-in-svg/53248462#53248462). Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying transformations to the svg element tag (**svg**) directly, you can use a group tag (**g**) to translate everything and a rectangle tag (**rect**) to scale only your 'viewbox'.

```
<svg width="1000" height="1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(1, 5)">
        <rect 
            id="viewbox"
            fill="black"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            transform="scale(2)" />
        <!-- your elements down here -->   
        <rect
            fill="grey"
            width="20"
            height="20"
            x="10"
            y="10" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Hope this help :)